# Bittrex API With PHP

Tags: php, api, bots

I'm trying to set up a bot for bittrex by using the bittrex api. I previously tried using python but had a hard time as the documentation was in php(https://bittrex.com/Home/Api), so I decided to switch to php. Im trying to create the bot but having a hard time starting. I pasted the initial code:

```
$apikey='xxx';
$apisecret='xxx';
$nonce=time();
$uri='https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/market/getopenorders?
apikey='.$apikey.'&nonce='.$nonce;
$sign=hash_hmac('sha512',$uri,$apisecret);
$ch = curl_init($uri);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('apisign:'.$sign));
$execResult = curl_exec($ch);
$obj = json_decode($execResult);
```

And according to this video: (sorry I had to add space because it doesn't allow me to post more than 2 links with low rep)

https:// youtu.be/K0lDTK3D-74?t=5m30s

It should return this: (Same as Above)

http:// i.imgur.com/jCoAUT9.png

But when I try place the same thing in a php values, with my own api key and secret I just get a blank webpage with nothing on it. This is what my php file looks like(API key and secret removed for security reasons):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/odMma.png

Any idea why this could be happening and how I could fix it?

Edit: No need for help anymore. I decided to go back to python and try to do it there and finally made it work :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The video you're working from has faked their results. Their code doesn't do anything with the value of `$obj`, so I wouldn't expect anything to show up on the web page. (And definitely not with the formatting they show.)

If you're unfamiliar enough with PHP that this issue wasn't immediately apparent to you, this is probably a sign that you should step back and get more familiar with PHP before you continue -- *especially* if you're going to be running code that could make you lose a lot of money if it isn't working properly.

Answer (score -1):

You need to `echo` your `$obj` or at least `var_dump()` it to see the content on a webpage.